Add CORS Origin list to Docker Compose
I would like to add my list of CORS origins to my docker-compose.yml file so it's easier to update/make changes. I can't seem to get this to work.  I've tried different ways of adding the list to the docker-compose environment variable, like removing/adjusting quotes, etc... but no luck.
server.js:
import cors from 'cors';

const corsOptions = {
  origin: [process.env.CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS],
  credentials: true,
  methods: 'GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type']
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

docker-compose.yml:
environment:
      - CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS='http://localhost:4200', 'https://test1.com', 'https://test2.com', 'https://test3.com'
      - PORT=5000

